# content-package-maven -plugin fails in removing a package from CRX

Tags: maven-2, jenkins, aem

I am trying to uninstall and remove a package from CRX de. For this I'm using "content-package-maven-plugin" and invoke a top level maven target in Jenkins with uninstall and rm as the goals for this plugin. The configuration are :
**-e com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.18:uninstall com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.18:rm**
The package is uninstalled successfully but the maven goal fails while removing the package with error like
[ERROR] Missing response status information in response:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
After this follows a html code. I tried to find out, what the issue could be was unable to figure out. Also, this issue is sporadic in nature i.e sometimes it fails, sometimes it succeeds. Hence reproducing it is also difficult.
Can you please help me find out what could be the issue so that I can atleast start moving in the direction of resolving it:)
Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like the plugin might not be waiting for a response long enough for the package to finish uninstalling. Does a small package size change behavior?

Comment: Hi bfitzpatrick, thanks for your reply. Never checked with a small package. But if at all, it is the case, how can we tell the plugin to wait till the task is finished.I'll also try n look into this...thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the link [here](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/missing-response-status-information-in-response-aem-installing/m-p/230838)?

Have you tried updating the content-package-maven-plugin ?

Looks like updating it to the latest version fixes the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).